# Detecting HTML textarea onkeyup event in JavaFX WebView

Tags: html, webview, javafx, javafx-2

I want to print the content of an HTML textarea inside WebView as soon as I type it.
PS: I tried listening to the `keyEvent` of `webView` for some reason it didn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. If you are trying to print content of **JavaFX TextArea** object into WebView then you should add listeners to TextArea not WebView.
2. If you are trying to listen for event in **HTML TextArea** tag inside HTML page in WebView you should add listeners to document model:

   ```
   // we need this to wait till document load
   webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
       public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
           if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {

               // note next classes are from org.w3c.dom domain
               EventListener listener = new EventListener() {
                   public void handleEvent(Event ev) {
                       System.out.println(ev.getType());
                   }
               };

               Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
               Element el = doc.getElementById("textarea");
               ((EventTarget) el).addEventListener("keypress", listener, false);
           }
       }
   });
   webEngine.loadContent("<textarea id='textarea'></textarea>");
   ```

Comment: How can I get access to textarea object inside handleEvent() method in EventListener?

Comment: What is the import for state ?

Comment: @NoorHossain `javafx.concurrent.Worker.State`