# Open Hyperlinks in JavaFX WebView with Default Browser

Tags: webview, javafx

I am writing a Java program that uses a Swing-based user interface, however I needed access to `WebView`, so I implemented a `JFXPanel` to take care of that. `WebView` is supposed to load an advertisement banner in to the program that the user can click on if the want. Currently, when the advertisement is clicked, the new page is loading within `WebView`. If possible, I would like to have the page open in the user's default browser and have the page containing the advertisement refresh. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HyperlinkListener in JavaFX WebEngine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555937/hyperlinklistener-in-javafx-webengine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue,
                    Worker.State newValue)
            {
            String toBeopen =
                            engine.getLoadWorker().getMessage().trim();
                    System.out.println("tobeopen: " + toBeopen);
                    if (toBeopen.contains("http://") || toBeopen.contains("https://")) {
                        engine.getLoadWorker().cancel();
                        try {
                                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL(toBeopen).toURI());
                            }
                            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                   }
          }
});
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: @AnhPham True, but at least it's a start. Thanks for being the first to step up and answer this Sanjay!