# javaFX 8 - How to get the link I click on, inside a WebView

Tags: java, html, javafx, webview, javafx-8

I got my first JavaFX 8 application with 2 WebViews.
The WebView on the left is made of a Table of Contents made in HTML that looks like that :

```
<div id="toc" class="toc">
    <div id="toctitle">Table of Contents</div>
        <ul class="sectlevel0">
             <li><a href="#_1_introduction">1 INTRODUCTION</a></li>
             <!-- other lines like the one just above -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the WebView on the right loads a HTML file. If I load it with "#_1_introduction" at the end of it's path, it will directly go on the introduction.

The thing is that I don't know how to get the "href" thing from the WebView on the left when the user clicks on it.

So my question is : "How do I get the string in the href line when a user clicks on it ?"

Thank you :)

Edit : I tried the code in [HyperlinkListener in JavaFX WebEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555937/hyperlinklistener-in-javafx-webengine) but it doesn't work, I mean, I don't even know what to import to make it work ;(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HyperlinkListener in JavaFX WebEngine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555937/hyperlinklistener-in-javafx-webengine)