# Block hyperlinks in a Javafx WebView / Web Engine

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a `WebView` in JavaFX. And I want add an event handler to decide if I want to block an hyperlink or redirect the user. I have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555937/hyperlinklistener-in-javafx-webengine). But there isn't a way described to block the redirection.

EDIT:

```
getWebEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                EventListener listener = new EventListener() {
                    public void handleEvent(Event ev) {
                        System.out.println("KLIKNIETO!!!");
                    }
                };

                Document doc = getWebEngine().getDocument();
                NodeList lista = doc.getElementsByTagName("a");
                System.out.println("Count: " + lista.getLength());
                for (int i=0; i<lista.getLength(); i++)
                    ((EventTarget)lista.item(i)).addEventListener("click", listener, false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Imports (**these were wrong**):

```
import org.w3c.dom.events.Event;
import org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener;
import org.w3c.dom.events.EventTarget;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you provided is a perfect solution. You propably want to `consume` the event to prevent the link to be openend/browser to be redirected. (Which is what you are looking for?)

I assume you know how to redirect and do the checks you mentioned. If not, pleaese elaborate a bit more what you are aiming for, and post some code of what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks but how do I consume an event?

Comment: @Ma_124 Assuming `e` is the passed in event (in the eventHandler), do `e.consume()`.

Comment: But in the interface `org.w3c.dom.events.Event` is no method like  `consume()` defined

Comment: @Ma_124 I think you got the wrong Event class.... JavaFX uses `javafx.event.Event` with `javafx.event.EventHandler` (and so does the author of the answer you posted). So either you use something different than javafx, or you used the wrong Event class. If you still can't find it, please post some code so we can take a look at it.

Comment: A right, I think they use `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` instead of `consume()`. Make sure to check if `getCancelaable()` returns true. Otherwise these methods won't work.

Comment: having the same problem, preventDefault() and stopPropagation() did not help. when i click the link, it is opened in the webview