# How to handle Javafx org.w3c.dom.Element cast to MenuItem error?

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I'm having issues creating a context menu for a WebView.

```
private void createContextMenuForButton(){
    MenuItem clickButton = new MenuItem("Click");
    clickButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent evt){
            addStep();
            ListItem item = ListItem.getListView().getItems().get(ListItem.getListView().getItems().size()-1);
            item.setComboBoxValue("Click");
            *String value = ((Element)evt.getTarget()).getAttribute("value").toString();*
            item.getWindow();
        }
    });
    listViewItemContextMenu.getItems().remove(0, listViewItemContextMenu.getItems().size());
    listViewItemContextMenu.getItems().add(clickButton);
}
```

When I run the method above I get the follow exception. Line 190 is marked with *. No matter how I try to get the elements of an ActionEvent it continue to get the error. I can't create an @FXML MenuItem because I need to be able to create new and different menuItem on the fly.

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.MenuItem cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
        at model.WebBrowser$4.handle(WebBrowser.java:190)
        at model.WebBrowser$4.handle(WebBrowser.java:1)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception, it looks like you are trying to cast a JavaFX `MenuItem` object to an `Element` type from the Java API for DOM from W3C. That doesn't make any sense. Doesn't it work without the cast, if what you are after is the value of the `MenuItem`? Try casting it to `MenuItem` instead of `Element`.

edit:

Ok had a more close look at it. Looks like it should be something like this, if what you want is the text value of the property `text`:

```
String value = ((MenuItem)evt.getTarget()).getText();
```

Comment: What I am after is the ActionEvent of the menuItem. Basically I set Listeners on the WebView, when the contextMenu is requested, the MenuItem is added and ActionEvent is set so that I can capture what part of the WebView is targeted. This is usually an HTML <INPUT>, for example. Then I can get the attributes based on the MenuItem Selection. So for example click, type, name, class, value etc of the INPUT.

Comment: If I cast MenuItem to the evt, I will get the text of the MenuItem. That's not what I need. That's why I cast org.w3c.dom.Element.

Comment: Oh sorry. Misunderstood. I was just focusing on the exception. In this case, you are listening to the wrong event. The action event returned here is the ActionEvent associated with `clickButton`. NOT with any of your DOM objects. Check this link for an idea of how to listen to events occurring inside the WebView. [link](http://blogs.kiyut.com/tonny/2013/07/30/javafx-webview-addhyperlinklistener/#.VmMI5_krLIU)

Comment: And similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555937/hyperlinklistener-in-javafx-webengine) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646865/detecting-html-textarea-onkeyup-event-in-javafx-webview)

Comment: You are right. I was using the wrong event. I redid it with the correct event, org.w3c.dom.events.Event. Now it has no error. Thank you for the help.